# How to prevent Rails controller from hanging when making a web service call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, faraday

I have a Rails controller that I'm calling when a user loads a specific page.  The controller makes a call to a 3rd party web service.  However, when the web service is down, my Rails controller just hangs.  I'm not able to navigate to another page, log out, or refresh the page...all of these tasks wait for the web service call to complete before being executed.  In the event that the web service call never completes, I have to restart my Rails app in order for it to be functional again.

Is there a standard way of preventing this from happening?  I am using the [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) gem to make web service calls.  I suppose I could set a timeout value when making my web service call.  However, ideally I would like any user action of navigating to another page to halt this web service call immediately.  Is this possible?

Comment: What is the rack implementation server that you are using?

Comment: @AmirRaminfar I'm not sure which Rack implementation I am using.  Do you happen to know how to check this?

Comment: If you don't know, then you are probably using Webrick which is default server in Rails. You shouldn't use that in production.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you are probably using a Rack web implementation that can only handle one request at a time. Unicorn is like that where it is event driven. Very much like Node. You should think about fixing this first with a timeout. So if you are using Faraday, you can do something like `req.options.timeout = 5` to have a timeout.

Then I recommend using Puma. If that's not an option, you should adjust your server settings to allow more than one connection at a time. For Unicorn, I believe it is `worker_processes`.

Comment: It worth noting that using multithreaded/multiprocess server will not prevent the controller's action from hanging. It's just other workers will be there for handling other requests in parallel to the hanging one. Therefore it is possible that all workers will become hanging when accessing that action.

Comment: Yea that's a good point. It's also worth pointing that depending on the load, it won't matter how many threads are available. At some point the system will degrade is performance.

Comment: Thank you AmirRaminfar and @NicNilov for your quick responses!  According to what you said, it looks like setting a timeout value for Faraday and using a different Rack implementation would make the user experience a lot better.  Thank you for the ideas!

Comment: This is the reason people are migrating to SPAs and writting APIs.